# Can't issue SEPA transaktions because account doesn't have SEPA information stored

Tags: gnucash

I have Gnucash 3.4-3 and Aqbanking 5.7.8-1 installed on Arch Linux.
When I try to issue a SEPA transaktion i get the error message:

> Your local bank account does not yet have the SEPA account information
>   stored. We are sorry, but in this development version one additional
>   step is necessary which has not yet been implemented directly in
>   gnucash. Please execute the command line program "aqhbci-tool" for
>   your account as follows: aqhbci-tool4 getaccsepa -b XXXXXXXX -a
>   XXXXXXXXXX

When I run the command it i don't get any errors but it changes nothing in gnucash.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Adding BIC and IBAN in account settings and then clicking get account info in special options resolved the problem!